# Why an attribute of a class be set a value, but print a None type?

Tags: python, class-attribute

Here is the code:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, animal_type):
        self.animal_type = animal_type

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, animal_type, favorite_food):
        super().__init__(animal_type)
        self.favorite_food = favorite_food

    def cat_print(self):
        print("{}'s favorite food is {}.".format(self.animal_type, self.favorite_food))

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        print('__getattribute__() be called. Item is: ', item)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print('__getattr__() be called. Item is: ', item)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print('__setattr__() be called. key and Value is: ', key, value)


cat = Cat('cat', 'fish')
print(cat.animal_type)
print(cat.favorite_food)
```

When I print the `cat.animal_type`, it print None. I guess that because of I rewrite method: `__setattr__()` and `__getattribute__()`, The value can't pass into the attribute.

I want to know what is the process of assigning attribute and get the attribute in a class in python?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `__getattr__` implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Anyway, yes, you’re right: the `__setattr__` override means an attribute never gets set and the `__getattribute__` override means an attribute that existed would never be read. Which part are you confused about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason all of your attributes are `None`, even non-existent attributes like `favorite`, is this:

```
def __getattribute__(self, item):
    print('__getattribute__() be called. Item is: ', item)
```

You're overriding the normal `object.__getattribute__` code with a method that always returns `None`. If you want it to print something *and also do the normal thing*, you have to do it explicitly, using `super`—the same way you already did in your initializer:

```
def __getattribute__(self, item):
    print('__getattribute__() be called. Item is: ', item)
    return super().__getattribute__(item)
```

---

If you fix that, lookup for attributes that exist will now work, but non-existent attributes are still going to return `None` instead of raising an `AttributeError`. Why?

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    print('__getattr__() be called. Item is: ', item)
```

The normal `object.__getattribute__` (that you're now properly calling) looks for an attribute in the object's `__dict__`, and in its class and all of its class's ancestors (with a bit of extra complexity related to descriptors that I'm going to ignore here), and then, if nothing is found (or something is found but fetching it raises `AttributeError`), it calls the class's `__getattr__`. And you provide a `__getattr__` that returns `None`.

Here, you again want to delegate to the superclasses:

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    print('__getattr__() be called. Item is: ', item)
    return super().__getattr__(item)
```

Except that there *is* no default implementation of `__getattr__`. So, you'll get an `AttributeError`, but it'll be about a `super` not having a `__getattr__`, not about a `Cat` not having a `favorite`.

If you know one of your base classes wants to provide a `__getattr__` for you to delegate to, `super` to it. But if you know nobody does:

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    print('__getattr__() be called. Item is: ', item)
    raise AttributeError(item)
```

And if you have no idea (because, say, your class was designed to be used as a mixin with someone else's class hierarchy), you probably want something like this:

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    print('__getattr__() be called. Item is: ', item)
    try:
        ga = super().__getattr__
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    else:
        return ga(item)
    raise AttributeError(item)
```

---

If you fix both of those, now you'll get an `AttributeError` on the attributes you *did* set. Why?

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    print('__setattr__() be called. key and Value is: ', key, value)
```

Same problem. Here, you might want to set the attribute explicitly, like this:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    print('__setattr__() be called. key and Value is: ', key, value)
    super().__getattribute__('__dict__')[key] = value
```

… or you might just want to delegate again:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    print('__setattr__() be called. key and Value is: ', key, value)
    super().__setattr__(key, value)
```

Comment: If the `Cat` has not a super class, the method isn't need the `super()` statement, but use the `self.` statement, am I right?

Comment: @xinchen No. if you just call `self.__getattribute__(item)`, you’re calling the exact same method, which will call the exact same method, which will… etc. 1000 times until you get a `RecursionError`. Also. `Cat` _always_ has a superclass—if nothing else, it’s `object`. And it’s the `object.__getattribute__` code that you ultimately want to be called here (unless some other intervening class wants to change that). So you definitely want `super`.

Comment: This is very helpful for me. And another question is what mean with `ga = super().__getattr` at second `__getattr__()` method? Is it `ga = super().__getattribute__(item)`?

Comment: @xinchen No. (It _is_ basically the same as `super().__getattribute__('__getattr__')`, but there's no reason to call it that way.) We're basically doing the same thing as `return super().__getattr__(item)`, except that there might be no `__getattr__` method on the superclass, and in that case, we want to make sure the caller gets an `AttributeError` about the `Cat` object not having an `item`, not an `AttributeError` about the `super` object not having a `__getattr__` (as explained in the answer).

Answer (score -3):

Add this in **init** in class Cat:

```
self.animal_type = animal_type
```

And modify your print

```
print(cat.favorite)
```

to

```
print(cat.favorite_food)
```

Then analyze and try to understand your mistake :)

Comment: No, the whole point of using `super` to call `__init__` is to not have to copy and paste the behavior of the base class's initializer.