# python oop class attribute returns None when set

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I'm trying to learn object orientated programming and when setting an attribute why does it return `None`?

Any tips on writing better code also appreciated... This is my class:

```
BEANS = ["black", "pinto"]
RICES = ["brown", "white"]
MEATS = ["chicken", "pork", "steak", "tofu"]


class Burrito:

    def __init__(self,
                meat,
                to_go,
                rice,
                beans,
                extra_meat=False,
                guacamole=False,
                cheese=False,
                pico=False,
                corn=False
                ):

        self.meat = self.setter("meat",meat)
        self.rice = self.setter("rice",rice)
        self.beans = self.setter("beans",beans)
        self.to_go = False
        self.extra_meat = False
        self.guacamole = False
        self.cheese = False
        self.pico = False
        self.corn = False

    def setter(self,category,attribute):

        print("category: ",category)
        print("attribute: ",attribute)

        if category == "meat":
            
            if attribute in MEATS:
                self.meat = attribute
            else:
                self.meat = False

        if category == "rice":
            
            if attribute in RICES:
                self.rice = attribute
            else:
                self.rice = False

        if category == "beans":
            
            if attribute in BEANS:
                self.beans = attribute

            else:
                self.beans = False
                
        else:
            self.category = "Error"
```

When I run this I expected the print to be `False` but returning `None`

```
noodle_burrito = Burrito("spagetti", True, True, False)
print("noodle_burrito.meat: ",noodle_burrito.meat)
```

And when I run this I expected the print to be `tofu` but returning `None`

```
vegg_burrito = Burrito("tofu", True, True, False)
print("vegg_burrito.meat: ",vegg_burrito.meat)
```

Thanks for any learning tips! Trying to reference this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740026/why-an-attribute-of-a-class-be-set-a-value-but-print-a-none-type) but I have never used `super` before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any function that doesn't explicitly return anything implicitly returns None.

Your `setter` function internally sets things, but has no other `return` statement, so

```
self.meat = self.setter("meat",meat)
```

ends up setting `self.meat` to None right after `self.setter` has already set it to something.

You're also not doing anything with more than half of the parameters your constructor accepts. I would write your class as

```
BEANS = {"black", "pinto"}
RICES = {"brown", "white"}
MEATS = {"chicken", "pork", "steak", "tofu"}


def validate_attr(value, options):
    if value in options:
        return value
    return False


class Burrito:
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        meat,
        rice,
        beans,
        to_go,
        extra_meat=False,
        guacamole=False,
        cheese=False,
        pico=False,
        corn=False,
    ):
        self.meat = validate_attr(meat, MEATS)
        self.rice = validate_attr(rice, RICES)
        self.beans = validate_attr(beans, BEANS)
        self.to_go = bool(to_go)
        self.extra_meat = bool(extra_meat)
        self.guacamole = bool(guacamole)
        self.cheese = bool(cheese)
        self.pico = bool(pico)
        self.corn = bool(corn)
```

Comment: thank you for this... Still learning here : )

Comment: Ill hit the green check when I can, what is `*,`? Never seen that before. Wildcard?

Comment: [In a function signature, it means the remaining arguments must be passed kwarg-only](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/#specification), i.e. you need to do `Burrito(meat=..., rice=...)`, etc; for a function that has many arguments, it makes it harder to accidentally pass a rice for a meat, or cheese for guacamole (which would be a no-no for a lactose-intolerant person!)

Comment: In your answer, `RICES`,`MEATS`,`BEANS` I notice you use dictionary instead of list. Is that a better choice than a list?

Comment: It's not a dictionary, it's a set. Sets are better when you don't care about the order of the items within, and want faster inclusion lookups.

Comment: Ah cool and with sets the items or keys all need to be unique right? That makes sense for this use case.

Comment: Yep - sets are unique-itemed and unordered; like dicts without values.

Answer (score 0):

Your setter sets the attribute, but then returns `None`, which you assign to the attribute again, overwriting whatever the setter itself assigned. Just drop the assignment in `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self,
            meat,
            to_go,
            rice,
            beans,
            extra_meat=False,
            guacamole=False,
            cheese=False,
            pico=False,
            corn=False
            ):

    self.setter("meat",meat)
    self.setter("rice",rice)
    self.setter("beans",beans)
    self.to_go = False
    self.extra_meat = False
    self.guacamole = False
    self.cheese = False
    self.pico = False
    self.corn = False
```

However, there's no reason for the `setter` method at all. Just assign values directly to the attributes.

```
class Burrito:

    def __init__(self,
                meat,
                to_go,
                rice,
                beans,
                extra_meat=False,
                guacamole=False,
                cheese=False,
                pico=False,
                corn=False
                ):

        self.meat = meat
        self.rice = rice
        self.beans = beans
        self.to_go = to_go
        self.extra_meat = extra_meat
        self.guacamole = guacamole
        self.cheese = cheese
        self.pico = pico
        self.corn = corn
```

Comment: How would I filter for bad attributes, what I was trying to define in `MEATS`, `RICES` ,`BEANS`?

Comment: You don't. `__init__`'s job is to simply do what the caller asks; it's their job to pass the correct arguments, and on them if they fail to do so. (But see [AKX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091635/1126841) for using a *different* function that *only* validates the arguments; I won't repeat it here.)